# Articles usage and human organs

Tags: articles, zero-article, scientific-language

As far as I know, usage of general concepts allows the usage of a **zero article**. But what about the **organs**, such as liver, lungs, or brain? Is it acceptable to use them without an article in academic writing, when we speak about general concepts of cognition, for example?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which organs and in what context?? Generally, if talking in generalities, one would still say: The human brain is a complex organ. BUT: Dissecting brains can be fascinating. So, it all depends on what you are actually saying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use "the" followed by "user" in "a window prompts the user to make..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/519651/why-do-we-use-the-followed-by-user-in-a-window-prompts-the-user-to-make) // The plural generic ('Brains are the most complex organs') obviously doesn't license an article. The definite and indefinite generic ('The brain is the most complex organ'; 'A brain is an extremely complicated structure') by definition use articles. Which is the usual choice here? I'd say the definite generic.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin and Lambie, that was very helpful! Indeed, the definite generic perfectly answers my question.

Comment: Should I delete the question as well? Or is it better to leave it here as a pointer?